# How to run Objective C program in terminal of my macbook pro?

Tags: xcode, terminal

I am totally new to xcode and macbook , i have developed a small ios application for ipad air running which in emulator is showing me white blank screen so thought of running it in terminal to debug the program , can anyone help me with this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your project builds and runs and shows a white screen in the simulator, there is likely a logic error in your code. If you want to make a console application you would have to create an osx command line project. Google debugging in xcode. Try a beginners tutorial that you can follow along and make something appear on your screen. Sprite kit games are easy to make and give quick results and satisfaction. Take a look at [this](http://www.johnandrewtorres.com/ios-tutorials/sprite-kit-first-game/) tutorial for basic sprite kit game.

Comment: Hi andrew my project is really very simple all i have done is placed a button clicking which shows some text in label that's all

Comment: Did you create a single view application?

Comment: Yes it is a single view app

Comment: in console it is saying "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

Comment: Sounds like your view controller is not hooked up to your storyboard. Go to your projects target window and in the deployment info section, make sure the main interface drop down box is on main.storyboard.

Comment: If u have created a single view application in xcode 6 and simply dragged a button onto the storyboard and run it, it should work

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
} , This is how my main.m code looks , is there any changes which I should make in this ?

Comment: No. You should never change the main file, you won't be working in there. For an application with just a button and text you should work in nothing but the storyboard and the view controller. Start a new project, follow a very basic tutorial step by step (google it) and good luck to you.

Comment: My code was build and  started showing up in simulator thank you , but how can I convert it into a app so that I can automate it using appium ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forget to set rootview controller . Go to your storyboard and check  Initailview controller is enable or disable

Comment: My code was build and  started showing up in simulator thank you , but how can I convert it into a app so that I can automate it using appium ?